# Retrieve the disk space information from multiple server

Tags: batch-file

I tried to login the sever from remote desktop and trying to retrieve the disk space. eg: from abs server I login to the cc server and trying to get disk space usage for cc server.

My code:

```
mstsc /v 112.345.56 /f
wmic /node 112.345.56 logicaldisk get caption free size
```

Comment: if you have required access to server , then you can get disk space details using wmic , no need to login again. BTW what is your issue here , not able to retrieve space details ? if you want space details for multiple servers you need to use the same command in a for loop

Comment: for each server we have credential so we need to login then we need to retrieve right.so I tried below code I can login to that particular server but I cant retrieve the details.so help me out.

Comment: check my answer , vote up if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

when you need to authenticate yourself when fetching target server details , you can do it with a single wmic command rather than using mstsc to connect.

```
WMIC /node:"yourserverip/name" /user:'username' /password:'password' LOGICALDISK GET Name,Size,FreeSpace
```

replace the values to suite to your need.

below values need to be replaced :

yourserverip/name : 112.345.56 [from your input]

username          : username to access above ip

password          : password to access above ip.

hope this helps.

Comment: @rins please accept my answer/vote up if it helped you. This will help users to find an answer for the same problem.

Comment: how can we convert into gb

Comment: yup , u have multiple ways to do it , if you are ok with approx value in gb then you can use something like this [SET /A TotalSpace=!TotalBytes:~0,-10!] here TotalSpace is the output of above command

Comment: how can I get folder size inside servers